# Log Trace.WriteLine in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-1.1

Our team has an ASP.NET Core Web Application which integrates Multisafepay payment provider (MSP). We use the .NET wrapper of MSP to communicate with the API of the payment provider. In some cases when we asking for the payment URL where the user can pay for his order we got an error code 9999 (unknown error). Mostly this happens after we restart our Web App in Azure or when it comes back from idle time.

I checked out the code of the MSP wrapper. It has some Trace.WriteLine statement in its code right where the error 9999 occurs. Is there any way to log the content of the trace in Azure?

I've tried almost everything. Modyfing the web.config, and adding trace listneres to it, turning on the Application Loggin and Log Stream in Azure, etc. but nothing worked.